# Ruby "Base" classes

Tags: ruby

It seems commonplace to name classes "Base" in Ruby. I'm not sure why, nor how I feel about it.

Consider, for example, [ActiveRecord](http://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activerecord/). `ActiveRecord` is a module that contains a number of classes such as `Observer` and `Migration`, as well as a class called `Base`. What's the benefit of this, as opposed to having an `ActiveRecord` class that contains `Observer` and `Migration`?

```
class ActiveRecord

  class Observer
    [...]
  end

  class Migration
    [...]
  end

end
```

vs

```
module ActiveRecord

  class Base
    [...]
  end

  class Observer
    [...]
  end

  class Migration
    [...]
  end

end
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `Base` class is commonly used to identify an abstract class, intended to be extended and implemented in a concrete class by the developer.

For instance, `ActiveRecord::Base` is the abstract class for any Active Record model in a Rails project. A model looks like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Likewise, `Observer` defines its own `Observer::Base` and Action Controller defines `ActionController::Base` which, in a Rails project, is immediately implemented by `ApplicationController::Base`.

Ruby doesn't provide and language-level keyword or syntax to define abstract classes. Technically speaking, `ActiveRecord::Base` it's not a real abstract class, but it's a kind of convention to use `Base` for this pattern.